# Failed to ResTable::remove()

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I'm having a problem with my android project.

When I launch my app in Eclipse, I got the following error in LogCat:

> **0x5ad3e5e0: Failed to ResTable::remove() cookie=0x4,not last table.**
>   mHeader.size() = 5.
>       Warning for spontaneous crashes when the garbage collector runs.
>       Error removing runtimes skin resource (cookie 0x4)

I don't know what it means or where it is coming from.

Everything still works fine, but the error message appears every time.

Comment: I am also getting same error in LogCat. Did you find the reason?

Comment: I believe this is an internal Android resource table, not related to your application.

Comment: what libraries do you have in your project??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear cache / data per application from settings (Applications -> manage applications). Try this [cache clearing](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5663/android-how-to-clear-browser-cache-history-form-data-andor-cookies/)